# Installed an RPM file. Where to find the installed program?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm

I have installed [xmedcon-0.11.0-1.i686.rpm](http://xmedcon.sourceforge.net/) on my Fedora Linux machine. I ran the `RPM` file. Since I'm kind of new to Linux, I want to ask, where can I find the installed file and how can I run it?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you just need to type the command in terminal as described here: http://xmedcon.sourceforge.net/Docs/ProgramGUI . Also, chances are the RPM has added an item to some menu. Look for it.

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 3):

From terminal use

```
$ rpm -ql xmedcon-0.11.0-1.i686 </code>
/etc/xmedconrc
/usr/bin/medcon
/usr/bin/xmedcon
```

You will see all the files installed. The main files will be above. From command line 
run

```
$ /usr/bin/xmedcon
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you already know the command name, you can type **which medcon** in a terminal and it should tell you where the executable is located.

And as full.stack.xchg said, just typing the name of the executable on a command line (or finding it in the graphical menu) will start the program.